# Categorizing the logging in enterprise logging c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

In my application I am logging the exceptions and warnings into a log file. Now I want to log these exceptions and warnings in to categories. There should be four methods corresponding to Critical, Error, Warning, Information, etc. How do I do that?

```xml
<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="Vodafone.DMS.AudioRecordingAgent.log.exclude" formatter="Text Formatter" rollInterval="Hour" rollSizeKB="1048576" traceOutputOptions="DateTime"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
        name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
```

```cs
LogInfo = Logger.LogInformation(1, DateTime.Now, ex.Message, string.Empty, parameterHashTable["FileName"].ToString());
```

Comment: Where is this LogInformation method coming from? I don't believe that is a method on the Logger class that is part of Enterprise Library. Normally you would call Logger.Write with a LogEntry. On the LogEntry you would set the Severity.

Comment: Also, if you are logging exceptions, you might want to look into using the Exception Handling Application Block. You don't have to hand code the LogEntry then, and you can get more useful information about the exception in your logs, such as the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType for this. It gives you the following enums:

```
EventLogEntryType.Error;
EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit;
EventLogEntryType.Information;
EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit;
EventLogEntryType.Warning;
```